# How is Fourier analysis related to this statement?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, waves, fourier-transform

The following statement is made when separating the spatial and time components of the field.
But I do not see how Fourier is related.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's related because it's the Fourier transform that tells us how to express any function $f(t)$ as an integral with components having time dependence $e^{-i\omega t}$, and therefore if we can analyze fields with time variation $e^{-i\omega t}$ we can analyze fields with any time-dependence we like.